# Why does this morphism factor through the reduction? (Lemma II.4.4 in Hartshorne)

Tags: algebraic-geometry, schemes

Let $R$ be a valuation ring of a field $K$. Let $T=\operatorname{Spec} R$ and let $U=\operatorname{Spec} K$.In Harthorne Lemma II.4.4 he proves that given a scheme $X$, a morphism of $T$ to $X$ is equivalent to giving two points $x_0,x_1$ in $X$, with $x_0 \in \overline{\{x_1\}}$ and an inclusion $k(x_1)\subseteq K$, such that $R$ dominates the local ring $\mathcal{O}$ of $x_0$ on the subscheme $Z= \bar{\{x_1\}}$ of $X$ with its reduced induced structure.

I am trying to understand the following step: write $t_0 = \mathfrak{m}_R$ and $t_1 = (0)$. 
Given a morphism $T \to X$ we let $x_0$ and $x_1$ be the image of $t_0$ and $t_1$ respectively. He then says "Since $T$ is reduced, the morphism $T \to X$ factors through $Z$ (Ex 3.11)"

The Ex 3.11 he is referring to, which I think he means 3.11 (c), requires 
i) the topological space of $T$ and $Z$ to be homeomorphic and ii) $T \to X$ has to be a closed immersion.

Any explanation on these two points would be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: I think Hartshorne is alluding to Ex 3.11 (d). As $T$ is reduced, we can give $Y=f(T)$ (I call $f:T \to X$ the map in question.) the reduced induced structure to get the scheme-theoretic-image. Then $T \to X$ factors through $Y \hookrightarrow X$ by Ex. 3.11 (d). But $Y= \overline{\{x_1\}} = Z$ in the above notation.

Comment: @JürgenBöhm I agree with you that it should be Ex 3.11 (d) but how is it that $f(T) = \overline{ \{ \ x_1\} }$?

Comment: I meant to say $Y:=\overline{f(T)}$ with the reduced induced structure. As one calls the scheme-theoretic image of $f:X \to Y$ often only by $f(X)$ but meaning $\overline{f(X)}$ with reduced induced structure (when $X$ is reduced), I confounded the two notations a bit.

Comment: @JürgenBöhm Sure, but then how do I deduce that $f$ factors through $Z$..?

Comment: As $Z$ is identical to $f(T)$ understood as $\overline{f(T)}$ the map $f:T \to X$ just factors by definition of the scheme-theoretic image.

Comment: @JürgenBöhm How is $f(T)$ identitcal to $Z= \overline{ \{x_1 \} }$? I am not seeing this...

Comment: Every $x' \in f(T)$ is a specialization of $x_1$, so $f(T) \subseteq \overline{\{x_1\}}$ (here $f(T)$ means set-theoretic image). So $\overline{f(T)} \subseteq \overline{\{x_1\}}$. On the other hand $\{x_1\} \subseteq f(T)$, so $\overline{\{x_1\}} \subseteq \overline{f(T)}$.

Comment: @JürgenBöhm Yes, thank you!